# error when using dplyr pipes on a 'partial' and 'data.frame' object

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate some summary statistics on a data object of classes 'partial' and 'data.frame'. However, I'm getting an error message returned that I don't know how to handle. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Below is the dummy data and code I tried.

Dummy data:

```
df <- structure(list(layer = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), depth = c(0.00956988699580556, 
0.00956988699580556, 0.00956988699580556, 0.00956988699580556, 
0.00956988699580556, 0.645324612566359), yhat = c(0.0579285714285714, 
0.0579285714285714, 0.0579285714285714, 0.0579285714285714, 0.0579285714285714, 
0), Variable = c("1 0.00956988699580556", "2 0.00956988699580556", 
"3 0.00956988699580556", "4 0.00956988699580556", "5 0.00956988699580556", 
"1 0.645324612566359"), Inter_Variable = c("Layer_Depth", "Layer_Depth", 
"Layer_Depth", "Layer_Depth", "Layer_Depth", "Layer_Depth"), 
    bins_Depth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0-5", 
    "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30", "30-35"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("data.frame", "partial"))
```

Code that returns an error:

```
df %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(bins_Depth, layer) %>% 
  summarise(ci =list(mean_cl_normal(yhat) %>% 
                       rename(mean = y, lwr = ymin, upr = ymax))) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(variance = (upr - lwr))
```

Here's the error message:

> Error in compositeSPC(object) :
> trying to get slot "horizons" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object
> In addition: Warning message:
> 'group_by' is deprecated.
> Use 'groupSPC' instead.
> See help("Deprecated")

EDIT: installed packages

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glatos)
library(VTrack)
library(cowplot)
library(beepr)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(maptools)
library(mlr)
library(iml)
library(magick)
library(pdp)
library(ranger)
```

Comment: I loaded tidyverse, your df, and the code you mentioned above with no problems. The only thing I got was a message with : `Warning message:
cols is now required when using unnest().
Please use cols = c(ci)`

Comment: The warning message re group_by indicates that you have another package loaded that is using this function. So add the packages you have loaded to your code. Since there seem to be conflicts, try changing your code by explicitly  calling the package of a function, e.g. dplyr::group_by.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Okay, i just copied your steps in a new R session and it works. But when i try to run it when all my other packages installed, i get returned the same error message. I'm copying all the packages that i loaded in my script to my OP, perhaps this is useful to figuring out the issue?

Comment: See deschens comment

Comment: Okay i found it: In my main script i only loaded essential packages that get me to where the error used to occur, and now it's gone. I'll do some further exploration to see which specific package causes the issue, and if repositioning within the list will fix it. To solve the new warning message, i typed unnest(cols = c(ci)).